# Automatic Configuration Using Bonjour

Tags: cups

[image]

I'm on `http://localhost:631/admin` (fedora) and attempting to install a printer via CUPS. I'm trying to find my URI to use:

```
lpinfo --include-schemes dnssd -v
```

returns no results? Is anyone skilled at setting up printers as this is kicking my ass - <s>nothing will print.</s>

I download and run the HP software.

```
./hplip-3.21.4.run
```

I'm now able to print although I have to switch my Wifi settings

[image]

to pick-up the printer - which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned WiFi settings, I assume you're trying to connect to the printer using a WiFi connection.

Normally, a WiFi network is set up by a router/base station, and any device connecting to it must be able to authenticate to it. In a typical home/small-business environment, this would mean that you need to supply two things to any device that needs to connect to your WiFi network:

- the name of the network
- the network password

**This is true for the printer too.** In order to communicate using your WiFi network, the printer needs to be able to connect to the router/base station, and to do that, it needs the two pieces of information as stated above.

Since the HP DeskJet 2700 series printers seem to have very simplified controls, you cannot just enter this information using the printer's control panel buttons.

If your router/base station supports Wireless Protected Setup (WPS), the simplest way would be to set the printer into wireless connection set-up mode (press and hold the Wireless button for at least three seconds), and then within two minutes, push a corresponding WPS button in the router/base station within a limited time: this allows the router/base station to supply the necessary connection details automatically to the printer. This is reasonably secure because it requires physical access to both devices.

The user guide for your printer provides other methods if your router/base station does not support WPS.

If the connection procedure described above is not done, the printer will not have any way to connect to your wireless network, because it does not have the necessary information to do so. Instead, it can act as a base station and provide its own WiFi network... and that's exactly what you are seeing with the `DIRECT-15-HP DeskJet 2700 series` wireless network. This scheme is also called "WiFi Direct".

If you don't have a computer with Windows that could be used to run HP's automatic wireless printer set-up utility (which can pass the necessary network credentials to the printer automatically), then you might use this printer's own wireless network to access the printer using a web browser: it should have a built-in web server that allows configuration access. You might use it to enter the wireless network name and password to the printer, then wait for the printer to reset and come up in your regular wireless network.

Once the printer is successfully connected to your normal WiFi network, then the `hplip` software should be able to find it without the need to switch WiFi networks.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, yes. I am trying to connect the printer using wifi. Great answer, very thorough - I'll attempt to create a small home network via my router settings via a browser. Alternatively, I could just patch it in using some ethernet I guess.

Comment: If you cannot use the WPS method, then 1.) connect to the `DIRECT-15-HP DeskJet 2700 series` wireless network, 2.) find the printer's IP address, 3.) point your web browser to the printer's IP, 4.) use the printer's web GUI to supply the authentication information for your normal WiFi to the printer, 5.) once the printer resets to make the new settings take effect, return to your normal WiFi network and the printer should now be connected to it too.

Comment: Great! I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: The WPS method worked for me thanks. Login to my router via a browser, enable WPS, hold and press the wifi button on the printer for 3 secs and finally, pair the router and printer with a press of the WPS pair button on the router itself.  No need to switch wifi networks - the machine sees the printer on the same network. Thanks again.